# PHP read lines not working on some computers but works on most

Tags: php

So im reading an CSV file and splitting it apart to get email,name,last name, however this outputs differently on different computers in my platform, let's say when I upload the same file it reads 38 lines and save them. However in 2 specific computers it reads only 1.

Before I was reading only TEMP file, but now im saving it to a directory and reading from there, however the problem is still here, I compared the file size and is the same even the content.
Is this a PHP bug ?

```
<?php
global $user;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) {

        $nome = $_POST['nome'];
        $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

        $user->criarLista($nome, $file);
    } else {
        $user->mensagem(1, "Não existe nenhum ficheiro");
    }

}
?>         

public function criarLista($nome,$file){

        // ADDED TO SAVE THE FILE IN THE SYSTEM AND READ FROM IT 
        if(file_exists("uploads/lista.txt")){ unlink("uploads/lista.txt"); }
        move_uploaded_file($file, "uploads/lista.txt");

        $file = file_get_contents("uploads/lista.txt");



        $user = $this->user;
        $get = $this->connect->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$user'");
        $fetch = $get->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $user_id = $fetch['id'];

        if($insert = $this->connect->prepare("INSERT INTO lista(user_id,nome) VALUES(?,?)")){
            $insert->bind_param("is", $user_id,$nome);
            $insert->execute();
            $list_id = $insert->insert_id;

            $file = preg_replace('#\\x1b[[][^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]#', '', $file);
            $file = strip_tags($file);
            $lines = file("uploads/lista.txt");

            $emails = array();
            $fnames = array();
            $lnames = array();
            $linha = 0;
            foreach($lines as $line) {

                if($linha == 0){

                }else{
                echo $Linha."</br>";
                    if (strpos($line, ',') !== false) {

                        $arr = explode(",", $line);
                        // Email \ FNAME | LAST

                        $emailx = trim($arr[0]);
                        $emailx = trim(preg_replace("/[\\n\\r]+/", "", $emailx));
                        array_push($emails,$emailx); 


                        if(isset($arr[1])){
                           $fname = trim($arr[1]);
                           $fname = str_replace('"','',$fname);
                           array_push($fnames,$fname); 
                        }

                        if(isset($arr[2])){
                           $lname = trim($arr[2]);
                           array_push($lnames,$lname); 
                        }

                    }else{
                       array_push($emails,trim($line)); 
                    }  

                }   

                $linha++;

            }

            array_map('trim', $emails);
            array_map('trim', $fnames);
            array_map('trim', $lnames);

            $emails = implode(",",$emails);
            $fnames = implode(",",$fnames);
            $lnames = implode(",",$lnames);

            if($insert_list = $this->connect->prepare("INSERT INTO listas(lista_id,email,primeiro_nome,ultimo_nome) VALUES(?,?,?,?)")){
                $insert_list->bind_param("isss", $list_id,$emails,$fnames,$lnames);
                $insert_list->execute();

                $this->mensagem(2,"Lista adicionada com sucesso");

            }else{
                echo 
                '
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    Erro: '.$this->connect->error.'
                </div>
                ';
            }


        }else{

            echo 
            '
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                Erro: '.$this->connect->error.'
            </div>
            ';

        }    

    }
```

FIXED this adding this on top of the function :

```
        ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',true);
```

Comment: are all your machines are Linux? Some Windows involved?

Comment: @Alex My machine is MacOS , and same as others , on windows works fine for all.

Comment: by "and same as others" you mean that all that DON'T work are MacOS, right?  That tells you something right there..... Somewhere I have some code that I had to fix the uploads from MacOS - I'll go look for it and post it (maybe someone will beat me to it... :) - as I recall, there is another file in there that you have to ignore - - don't remember, but will go look now....

Comment: Saying works on some but not on others is like having a weather forecast saying in some areas of the world the weather will be good in others not XD You have to specify the systems where the problems occur and also where not otherwise this question is really useless.

Comment: @CFPSupport The thing is that is not all Mac's because both my laptop and Desktop is Mac, but the issue was verified on 2 other different Macs , on the windows computers there was no issue. Thanks ill expect for it

Comment: @Blackbam It's hard to explain, the issue was verified on only 2 Mac computers , however on my Mac laptop and Desktop works just fine, that's why I don't know what's happening, first I was reading only temp file, but now im moving the file into the server and only then I read it, however the problem for those 2 persist

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is an 'answer' to what is going on, though it is what I had to do to fix an issue with a Mac user sending files.

What I found was that, every time he did an upload, it would send a .zip file, not just the file (like the PCs did).  I did not have other Mac users to test against, so, again, I can't say this is exactly the issue you have, but I trust it will at least help in your search.

Note that I had to chop a lot of code out of this (where I was doing various other functions with the database, etc.), so this may not run directly, but I think I closed all the 'ifs' and such - or you can figure it out (if not, let me know and I'll go through it again).

Hope this helps!

```
$save_file = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$zipfile='maps/'.$save_file;  // location of a temp location (stops double uploads)
$alert_upload_file_exists = "Uploaded file exists!";   
$alert_upload_successful = "UPLOAD SUCCESSFUL"; 
$action_failed_text = "Action FAILED";
if(file_exists($zipfile) && (empty($_GET['overwrite']) || $_GET['overwrite'] == 'false')) 
    die($alert_upload_file_exists);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $zipfile))
{
    // I found this mac to be sending a .zip file, not a standard one..... :(
    $uploadOk = 0;
    $mac_file = 0;
    if($basename = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"],".zip"))
    {
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        if($zip->open($zipfile) === true){
            // echo "basename is $basename<BR>";
            for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
                $filename = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
                $fileinfo = pathinfo($filename);
                // look for the file we really want (in our case, any sort of img file)
                if($fileinfo['basename'] == $basename . '.png' || $fileinfo['basename'] == $basename . '.jpg'  || $fileinfo['basename'] == $basename . '.gif') {
                    $imgfile = $_GET['loc_data_id'].".".$fileinfo['extension'];
                    $files[]=$fileinfo['basename'];
                //      echo "file added to the list <BR>";
                }
                 //  echo "filename is $filename, basename is ->".$fileinfo['basename']."<- fileinfo = ";print_r($fileinfo);
                 // CHECK TO SEE IF THIS WAS THE 'WEIRD' MAC FILE               
                 if($fileinfo['basename'] == "__MACOSX") 
                     $mac_file = 1;
                //   echo "mac_file is $mac_file ";
            }
            if(($imglist = array_keys(array_flip(preg_grep('/^.*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/i',$files))))
            {
            //          echo "imglist = ";print_r($imglist);
            //  echo "files = ";print_r($files);
                foreach($files as $key => $value)
                {
                    if ($imglist[0]==$value) {$file = $imgfile;}
                    $upgrade += file_exists('maps/'.$file);
                    //  echo "imgfile is $imgfile, file is $file upgrade is $upgrade and value is ".$basename."/".$value." ............";
                    // more 'FUNNY BUSINESS' to work the Mac file....
                    if($mac_file){
                        $extracted = $zip->extractTo('maps/',$basename."/".$value);
                        rename("maps/$basename/$value","maps/$file");   
                    }
                    else {
                        $extracted = $zip->extractTo('maps/',$value);
                        rename("maps/$value","maps/$file"); 
                    }
                }
                // AND A BIT MORE.....
                if($mac_file){
                    rmdir ("maps/$basename");
                }
                $zip->close();
                $imgcount=0;$mapcount=0;$uploadOk=1;
                $html = file_get_html('maps/'.$mapfile);
                $imgck = strpos($html,'<img ');
                if(($imgck===false) || $imgck<>0) {
                    $uploadOk += 2;
                }
                //      echo "uploadOk is $uploadOk<br>";
                if($uploadOk==1)
                {
                    $mapname = pathinfo('maps/'.$mapfile);
                    //  echo "mapfile is $mapfile, mapname = ";print_r($mapname);
                }
            }
            else $uploadOk += 20;
        }
    }
    if($uploadOk==1) echo basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])." ".$alert_upload_successful;
    else echo $action_failed_text . " ".$uploadOk;
    // delete the original .zip file (and any that are in the 'maps/' folder)
    array_map('unlink', glob("maps/*.zip"));
}
else
{
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    echo "temp name is " . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]. " save file is ". $save_file."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, it gave me a new insight, i just found out that thoose macs who submit their cvs are not comming with lines defined properly, so after a good search i found this which fixed my issue:         ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',true);

Comment: Glad you found that - it was one of the things I thought about as well, then got tied up in finding the code above.  Wish it had been "the" answer for you, but glad you got things going.

Comment: you provided great help, if it was not for you help i would not consider that mac's would have strange behaviours on file uploading,  also it's great content you provided there for future reference, ill save people lifes !